# covert date to Julian date in bigquery

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, google-bigquery, julian-date

I have a requirement where I need to convert current_date to Julian date in Bigquery. How to do that?

Oracle query
select
to_char(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC (CAST (TRUNC (SYSDATE + 550) AS TIMESTAMP)),
'J') from dual

I need to rewite above in Bigquery